# when I type 'no' it still repeats anyway, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

trying to ask user to play or not but when I type no it repeats anyway regardless

```
import random

play = True

while play:
  
  secret = random.randint(1,101) 

  while True:
    guess = int(input("Input your guess: "))
    if guess == secret:
      print ("Correct!")
      again = str(input("Do you want to play? (Type Yes or No): "))
      break 
    elif guess < secret:
       print ("Too Low")
       continue
    elif guess > secret:
       print ("Too High")
       continue
      
   

if again == "no" or "No":
   play = False
```

I want to be able to type 'yes' and plays the guessing game again and when I type 'no' it stops

Comment: Welcome to SO.  ```if again == "no" or "No":``` doesn't do what you think it does.  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Comment: After changing the ```if again == ...``` line, you should indent it more to be within the ```while play``` loop so that it changes the ```play``` value to break out of the outter while loop.

Comment: @Amadan, that is incorrect.  Reading from a file will have newlines, but `input()` strips it off for you.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Learn something every day... Thank you!